# loading page after clicking on element in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a page loaded using puppeteer and I have list of elements rendered in this page. Each of the elements can be clicked and on click it will expend the element and add additional element with more data. Kind of like en accordion. How can I make it worked? I tried couple of things like:

```
async function getSite(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

  const parentElements = await page.$$(".feeditem");
  await Promise.all(parentElements.map(parentElement => parentElement.click()));

  await page.waitForFunction(
    parentNumber =>
      document.querySelectorAll(".accordion_opened").length === parentNumber,
    { timeout: 20000 },
    parentElements.length
  );

  await page.waitFor(5000);

  const elementsExtcArr = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion_opened"));
    const elementsExtc = elements.map(i => i.innerHTML);

    return elementsExtc;
  });

  console.log(elementsExtcArr);
  await browser.close();
}

getSite(url);
```

but none of those not work. I still getting the page as it was before the clicks events. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this at first:

```js
const elements = await page.$$(".feeditem");
await Promise.all(elements.map(element => element.click()));

let site = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelector("body").innerHTML
);
```

If this does not help (say, if each click sends a XHR request and you need to wait more), you can add a [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args), like this:

```js
const parentElements = await page.$$(".feeditem");
await Promise.all(parentElements.map(parentElement => parentElements.click()));

await page.waitForFunction(
  parentNumber => document.querySelectorAll('.accordion_opened').length === parentNumber,
  { timeout: 0 },
  parentElements.length
);

let site = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelector("body").innerHTML
);
```

Comment: unfortunately it not worked. I updated the question with the full code maybe you could see something i missed, thank you.

Comment: @obiwankenoobi What URL do you use?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi Sorry, I've made a typo. Please, replace `document.querySelectorAll('.accordion_opened')` with`document.querySelectorAll('.accordion_opened').length` as in the edited answer and try again

Comment: no still return an empty array. The url im trying to work with is `https://www.yad2.co.il/realestate/rent`

Comment: When I try to open the site in a common browser, I get this message:"מתנצלים, המחשב חסום לגישה לאתר.
האתר משתמש בשירות אבטחה לצורך מניעת תקיפות מקוונות. 
ביצעת פעולה אשר הפעילה את שירות האבטחה וחסמה את גישתך.

Incident מספר פניה: 1fa2753ea52adee59f2e0460463a662a
ליצירת קשר עם מוקד שירות לקוחות 
טלפון : 03-5522222
מוקד טלפוני ארצי פועל בימים א-ה
שעות פעילות 09:00-18:00"

Comment: The same in firefox. I only tried to open it the very first time. It seems the blocking is based on country or some IP segment. Sorry(

Comment: anyway the method using `$$` seems like it's not returning any values, but `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".feeditem"));` does. There is any chance to use click on each of the elements using that?

Comment: Oh, maybe this is another typo? In your code there is `await page.$$("feeditem");` instead of `await page.$$(".feeditem");` (with `.` in class selector).

Comment: yep the typo was a problem but now the click still not rendering the sections I am trying to render. the `waitForFunction` call is timeout. Seems like the click simply not working

Comment: Can you try in the browser console if after all clicks `document.querySelectorAll(".feeditem").length === document.querySelectorAll(".accordion_opened").length` as we suppose this should be true. If there are other elements with this classes outside our scope, this is the issue.

Comment: so I tried to `console.log(parentElements)` and it returns  `ReferenceError: parentElements is not defined` when we clearly defined it here: `const parentElements = await page.$$(".feeditem");` I think it might be the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188185/discussion-between-obiwankenoobi-and-vsemozhetbyt).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing everything in the browser context:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  for(let el of [...document.querySelectorAll('.feeditem')]){
    el.click()
  }
})
```